# Spring Data R2dbc Auditing does not work as expected

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

My sample codes are based on Spring Boot 2.4.0-M2(spring-data-r2dbc 1.2.0-M2), Java 11, Postgres.

In the spring blog and change log, it delcares Spring Data R2dbc got audting support.

I Enabled auditing like this.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcAuditing
class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    ReactiveAuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return () -> Mono.just("hantsy");
    }
}
```

And entity class and repository.

```java
interface PersonRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Person, UUID> {
}

@Data
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(value = "persons")
class Person {

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column("created_at")
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column("updated_at")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @Column("version")
    @Version
    private Long version;

}
```

Schema script. (no worry about the UUID, the extension initialized in docker init scripts)

```sql
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons (
 -- id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  first_name VARCHAR(255),
  last_name VARCHAR(255),
  created_at TIMESTAMP ,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP,
  version INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
```

When I added the following code fragments in the `ApplicationRunner` to experience the auditing, none of `@createdDate` and `@lastModifiedDate` are filled.

```java
            persons
                    .save(
                            Person.builder()
                                    .firstName("hantsy")
                                    .lastName("bai")
                                    .build()
                    )
                    .log()
                    .map(person -> {
                        person.setFirstName("new Hantsy");
                        return person;
                    })
                    .flatMap(persons::save)
                    .log()
                    .then()
                    .thenMany(persons.findAll())
                    .subscribe(
                            data -> log.info("saved data: {}", data),
                            err -> log.error("err: {}", err)
                    );
```

The console prints:

```sh
2020-09-07 22:12:30.734  INFO 8800 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.Mono.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Person(id=8814e87c-c6d3-4dca-a095-fb5f41696b49, firstName=hantsy, lastName=bai, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null, version=0))
2020-09-07 22:12:30.779  INFO 8800 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.Mono.UsingWhen.1                 : onComplete()
2020-09-07 22:12:30.801  INFO 8800 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.2                   : | onNext(Person(id=8814e87c-c6d3-4dca-a095-fb5f41696b49, firstName=new Hantsy, lastName=bai, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null, version=1))
2020-09-07 22:12:30.801  INFO 8800 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.2                   : | onComplete()
2020-09-07 22:12:30.823  INFO 8800 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : saved data: Person(id=981741c3-4468-474d-9e92-b4d396f004d9, firstName=hantsy, lastName=bai, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null, version=0)
2020-09-07 22:12:30.824  INFO 8800 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : saved data: Person(id=8814e87c-c6d3-4dca-a095-fb5f41696b49, firstName=new Hantsy, lastName=bai, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null, version=1)
```

**Updated**: Created [another simple example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-data-r2dbc-auditing)(based on H2) for r2dbc auditing to reproduce it, the testing codes work, but application is still problematic. Not sure if my original example(based on Postgres, and used Pg specific JSON, Enum, etc.) requires other configs, none of the application and the testing codes work as expected.

**Updated**: A related issue was reported in Github issues, see [issues#451](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/451). Updated [my sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-r2dbc-auditing) to make sure the fixes is applied in the 1.2.0 snapshot20200910 version. I think the next version(1.2.0-RC1) will include the fixes.

**Updated**: my sample is updated to Spring Boot 2.4.0-M3, the bug is fixed.

Comment: When filling the createdDate and lastModifiedDate, the auditoraware is not a must.

Comment: `The annotations capturing when changes were made can be used on properties of type Joda-Time, DateTime, legacy Java Date and Calendar, JDK8 date and time types, and long or Long` maybe not LocalDateTime so try changing it to only DateTime